# Position the button in right place Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

How can I position the two button close to eachother. I am getting the output as shown in the picture below.

```
 _scrape_btn = ttk.Button(_mainframe, text='Scrape!', command=save)
 _scrape_btn.grid(row=2, column=0)

 _compress_btn = ttk.Button(_mainframe, text='Compress!', command=compress)
 _compress_btn.grid(row=2, column=1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your image, I can tell that your *URL* and *Content* LabelFrames have been put into `row=0, column=0` and `row=1, column=0` respectively. So you should now realise that the width of the first column is as large as the labelframe. Hence your 2nd button starts where the 1st column ends since it on the 2nd column.

What you can do is add `columnspan=2` in both the labelFrames.

Now by default the buttons will be center aligned. To bring them close together, you need to add `sticky='e'` in the grid command of the 1st button (*Scrape*) and `sticky='w'` in the grid command of the 2nd button (*Compress*).